# XPages Design Definition for a custom control

Tags: jsp, xpages

In XPages Design Definition how can I get the name of the custom control. I found

```
<%=this.viewName %>
```

but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: with *this* you will only have access to the custom control properties. Please have a look here: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.de/2010/01/xpages-using-powerful-design-definition.html

Comment: Thanks Sven - so there is no way to get the custom control name then?

Comment: If you have Design Definitions, why not just type the name in there?

Comment: That's what I have been doing - but was hoping if there was a lazy way to copy and paste and automate this task - thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage this is not possible based on the response above. I have to manually achieve this by typing in the name of the custom control.

Answer (score 0):

XPages is JSF not JSP. So JSP constructs will not work (other than in the design definition).
Thus `<%` is not a supported construct in XPages. The EL syntax is `#{...}` or `${...}`. Did you try to use the view object? it is a `com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2` and you either could use the class or [query a property](http://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xp_view.html) or better use the [API Inspector](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20API%20Inspector). At least the className will give you what you are looking for

Comment: The question is about the design definition of CCs: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/16102009115724SCAEXA.htm

Answer (score 0):

The xp.image tag in the Design Definition DOES work in xpages.
A design definition speeds uploading in the DDE, without the Design Definition the tags are computed and slows slows sloows down xpage from loading in the DDE, I find.
[XPages Design Definition for a custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193916/xpages-design-definition-for-a-custom-control/48551751#48551751)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:div style="background-color:blue; color:white; padding:3px;">
Begin This is Month Picker Custom Control</xp:div>
<xp:image url="/esaCboxFilters.GIF"></xp:image> 
<xp:panel> 
tagCloud for <!-- %=this.viewName % this does not work --> 
</xp:panel> 
</xp:view>
```

[image: How the Design Definition Looks in the Design Pane]